# What is the point of registered ports?

Tags: networking, port, client-server

I am developing a system which requires client/server communication, having read some of the IANA documentation it states:

> The Registered Ports are assigned by IANA and on most systems can be used by ordinary user processes or programs executed by ordinary users. The Registered Ports are in the range 1024-49151.

> Assigned ports both System and User ports SHOULD NOT be used without
> or prior to IANA registration.

My questions are:

1.Can I use the registered ports range for my software that I will distribute publicly? (without regard for assigned spaces) "Should not be used without or prior to IANA registration."

2.It seems to state "can be used by ordinary user processes or programs executed by ordinary users" but what does this mean exactly?

3.This may sound like a stupid question, but is IANA a government regulated body? What's stopping someone from using ports assigned to popular software and binding to them quicker?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority for #3

Comment: I would suggest primarily having a config option to be able to change the port your "server" listens on. If that port is already being used, maybe it has a small range of known backup ports.  As long as the client, has this known set and also a explicit config option, this should make it relatively fool proof out of the box.  I would suggest incrementing by 1 for say a five port range.  At least your documentation can suggest the range for those not able to exclude by process. There is no need to register a port as it's all pretty much the wild west beyond 1024.

Comment: Read about ports below 1024 to find the answer to question #2.